# SVG filter not being masked as expected in Chrome 87 when mask is curved

Tags: google-chrome, svg, filter, mask

In Chrome, since the update to v87, masks and filters in SVGs are behaving in an unexpected way for me when the mask has curves.

Here is an example:

```html
<svg width="226" height="226" viewBox="0 0 226 226" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<mask id="mask0" mask-type="alpha" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="38" y="39" width="148" height="148">
<path d="M112 187C152.869 187 186 153.869 186 113C186 72.1307 152.869 39 112 39C71.1307 39 38 72.1307 38 113C38 153.869 71.1307 187 112 187Z" fill="#F0F1F2"/>
</mask>
<g mask="url(#mask0)">
<g filter="url(#filter0_d)">
<rect x="12" y="67" width="202" height="92" fill="#4D9DE6"/>
</g>
</g>
<defs>
<filter id="filter0_d" x="2" y="59" width="222" height="112" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"/>
<feOffset dy="2"/>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5"/>
<feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow" result="shape"/>
</filter>
</defs>
</svg>
```

In Chrome 86, and in current versions of all major browsers, the behaviour is expected, and the blue rectangle with the drop shadow is masked with a circular shape. But Chrome 87 renders it differently:

[Example image of the way the SVG is rendered in other browsers/Chrome 86, and in Chrome 87](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWNMo.png)

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Can repro, has already been fixed in Chrome 88 https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1153600

Comment: Aha, thank you @Kaiido !